# Returning a global array in c++

Tags: c++

How do I return a global array that was populated inside a function so that I can use it in other functions in C++?

for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int global[10]

//POPULATE THE ARRAY HERE
int functionReturnArray()
{
int i;

     for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
     {
      global[i] =i;

      if(i==9)
        {
         return global;
         }
      } 

}//close function

int main()
{
      int local = functionReturnArray();
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      local[i];// I WANT TO USE THE ARRAY HERE
      return 0
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In your example, you should simply change `int local` to `int* local`, but if it's in the same file, you don't need to return it. You can simply refer to it inside any of the functions within this file.

Comment: I might be missing something, but your main already has access to global... Why the need to return? A better design is to rename int functionReturnArray() to void functionInitalizeArray() and forget about return values. Also, your main should read int main(int argc, const char *argv[])

Comment: @Freddy, no! `int main()` is perfectly valid, I never understand why people insist on declaring parameters to `main` that they don't use. In fact the _only_ two portable declarations for `main` are `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)` so it's implementation-defined whether `const char* argv[]` is valid!

Comment: @JonathanWakely Correct. I guess old habits die hard.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I return a global array that was populated inside a function so that I can use it in other functions in C++?

You can't return an array in C++, or pass it to a function, because arrays "decay" to a pointer to their first element.

You could return `int*` instead, but as the comments above say, if t he array is global why do you need to return it anyway? Globals are accessible globally, just use it directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return array,
you can only return pointer to the array (return type int*).

```
int global[10]

int* functionReturnArray()
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        global[i] = i;
    }
    return global
}

int main()
{
    int* local = functionReturnArray();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        local[i]; // I want to use the array here
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: This approach is probably the easiest and the most straight forward for me to implement. However my program keeps crashing.                  I want to provide more description but cant do it here on the comment section. Should just modify the original post?

Comment: I believe yes. update the original (mark what was edited, so others also know what changed)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays have neither copy constructor nor copy assignment operator.

Here are some approaches to the task

Using a local reference to the global array:

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 10;

int global[N];

int ( &functionReturnArray() )[N]
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        global[i] = i;
    }

    return global;
}

int main() 
{
    int ( &local )[N] = functionReturnArray();

    for ( int x : local ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Using a pointer to the first element of the global array

```
#include <iostream>

const size_t N = 10;

int global[N];

int * functionReturnArray()
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        global[i] = i;
    }

    return global;
}

int main() 
{
    int *local = functionReturnArray();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) std::cout << local[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Using standard class std::array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

const size_t N = 10;

int global[N];

std::array<int, N> functionReturnArray()
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        global[i] = i;
    }

    std::array<int, N> a;

    std::copy( global, global + N, a.begin() );

    return a;
}

int main() 
{
    std::array<int, N> local = functionReturnArray();

    for ( int x : local ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The advantage of the first and third approaches is that local arrays (the reference and the object of type std::array) keep information about their sizes.

Comment: on number one I get the following errors: 1. "In function int main()" 2. "expected initializer before ':' token", 3.expected ')' before ';' token. how can I fix it?

Comment: @user1774537 It seems you made a typo. If to copy and paste the code of the first example then it is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

you should return a pointer to the first element in the array

```
int* functionReturnArray()
```

then you can use it in the main function

```
int main()
{
      int *local = functionReturnArray();
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      local[i];// I WANT TO USE THE ARRAY HERE
      return 0
}
```